# Simplified coding for a lot of variables in vba

Tags: vba, variables

I have 100 boxes, (box1, box2, etc) each box has 100 rows of values. (0,1,2,etc) So I have a total of 10,000 rows of data. I am counting number of cells in each box with a specific value. I set the range because I can then change the countif value, e.g. number of cells with value of 2, 3, etc.

However, to do this, I have to Dim boxes 100 times and set box= 100 times. Is there a way to simplify this? Each box always has 100 rows, total number of boxes is always 100.

```
Dim box1 As Range
Dim box2 As Range
Dim box 3 As Range
.....

Set box1 = Range("A1:A100")
Set box2 = Range("A101:200")
Set box3 = Range("A201:300")
.....

Range("C1").formula = "=COUNTIF(box1, "1")"
Range("C2").formula = "=COUNTIF(box2, "1")"
.....
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started in the right direction:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim box(1 To 100) As Range
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(box)
        Set box(i) = Cells(100 * (i - 1) + 1, "A").Resize(100)
        Cells(i, "C").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & box(i).Address & ",""1"")"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant! What does the Resize(100) do?

Comment: And what if I want to display the result starting in C2? I actually want to display the result for box 1-50 in column C, box 51-100 in column D. And I can't just change to Cells(i,"C2")